# Adding 'Edit' Ajax.ActionResult to render on same page in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

My first ever Ajax request is failing, and I'm not quite sure as to why.

I've used the MVC scaffolding in order to create a table (which uses a default `@Html.Actionlink`). However, I'm looking to include an 'edit' section on the same page via ajax requests.

So my table now has:

```
  <td>
     @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.OID}, new AjaxOptions { 
                                               UpdateTargetId = "editblock", 
                                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                                               HttpMethod = "GET" }
     ) |
```

As suggested [here](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/ajaxactionlink-and-htmlactionlink-in-mvc.html).

Within the same view i have a div defined as:

```
<div id="editblock">
    Edit Section Here
</div>
```

And My controller is defined as:

```
public PartialViewResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return PartialView(new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
            }
            TableModel tablevar = db.TableModel.Find(id);
            if (tablevar == null)
            {
                return PartialView(HttpNotFound());
            }
            return PartialView("Edit", tablevar );
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public PartialViewResult Edit( TableModel tablevar )
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tablevar ).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            return PartialView("Edit",tablevar );
        }
```

My "Edit.cshtml" looks like:

```
@model Project.Models.TableModel

<body>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
```

Could anyone suggest as to why this is failing, and what I ***should*** be doing instead to render this partial view onto the page (as currently it keeps redirecting to new page and not showing on 'index' screen)?

Answer (score 0):

Place those scripts at the bottom of your view. By the time they execute your form isn't present (and therefore the auto-wireup fails). In general, you want `<script>` tags as close to the `</body>` tag as possible to your content is there before the script executes.

Other than that, you look fine.

Comment: That didn't make a difference I'm afraid :(.

Comment: @jbutler483: As something you can use as a reference, check out my [MvcAjaxDemo](https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples/tree/question-24312194/MvcAjaxDemo). It's not a one-to-one of your solution, but does use the Ajax helpers to retrieve content.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'll definitely look into that as it's doing my head in! every thing seems Identical to the examples i've seen, so I honestly don't know why this isn't doing what it should!